# iPhone - access location information from a photo

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geolocation, geocoding

Is it possible, in an iPhone app, to extract location information (geocode, I suppose it's called) from a photo taken with the iPhone camera?

If there is no API call to do it, is there any known way to parse the bytes of data to extract the information? Something I can roll on my own?

Comment: [solution using Photo framework in **iOS 8**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33672661/1378447)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

The problem is thus;

A jpeg file consists of several parts. For this question the ones we are interested in are the image data and the exif data. The image data is the picture and the exif data are where things like geocoding, shutter speed, camera type and so on are stored.

A UIImage (and CGImage) only contain image data, no tags.

When the image picker selects an image (either from the library or the camera) it returns a UIImage, not a jpeg. This UIImage is created from the jpeg image data, but the exif data in the jpeg is discarded.

This means this data is not in the UIImage at all and thus is not accessible.

Comment: Is there any known way to parse the bytes of data to extract the information? Perhaps not an API call, but something I can roll on my own?

Comment: Afraid not, I've clarified the answer to explain why.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. It's possible, as some apps (such as Mobile Photos and PixelPipe) seem to be able to manage it. I still haven't found any sample code though.

Answer (score 2):

I think the selected answer is wrong, actually. Well, not wrong. Everything it said is correct, but there is a way around that limitation.

`UIImagePickerController` passes a dictionary along with the `UIImage` it returns. One of the keys is `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` which is "the filesystem URL for the movie". However, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280479/in-the-uiimagepickercontroller-is-it-possible-to-get-the-nsurl-value-for-uiimage/3394878#3394878) in newer iOS versions it returns a url for images as well. Couple that with the [exif library](http://iphone-exif.googlecode.com/files/iphone-exif-guide-0.8.pdf) mentioned by @Jasper and you might be able to pull geotags out of photos.

I haven't tried this method, but as @tomtaylor mentioned, this has to be possible somehow, as there are a few apps that do it. (e.g. [Lab](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lab/id370554283?mt=8)).

Comment: When i tried this (iOS 4.2) it does not return that key - just UIImagePickerControllerMediaType, UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage and UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, which was `"assets-library://asset/asset.jpg?id=2317&ext=jpg"`

Comment: Good to know... Maybe it was just there in 3.2?

Comment: I can confirm that picking a photo from the Saved Photos Album only gives you back the three keys Alex mentioned. When picking from the camera, as the OP was interested in, you get neither UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL nor UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL.