# play video from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iOS

Tags: iphone, url, video, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm still fairly new to Obj-C and the idea of blocks. I read this post about displaying images from url retrieved from ALAssets: [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

Besides being able to view picture files in a `UITableView` using the `ALAsset` framework, I want to be able to play a video that is stored in the pictures folder as well. The video asset shows up just as a picture would, so I would like to be able to tap that video listing in the table and have it play. (In other words, I want to play a video using the Assets Library Framework)

Can this be done with `MPMoviePlayerController`?

From that post above I'm gathering I need code inside this function to get an asset URL for a video file:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
    };
```

If this is right, what code would I need to put inside that function so that I could successfully play the video via `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Just for reference, my code for displaying the assets in a `UITableView` is here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"id";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


 [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] thumbnail]]];
 [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", indexPath.row+1]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is my first post so I'm sorry if I post it wrong. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found out one can use this block to spit out a log of the asset library address:

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
{

   if(result != nil) {
        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
        [assets addObject:result];

    }
};
```

which will spit out something like

```
"See Asset: ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{
    "com.apple.m4v-video" = "assets-library://asset/asset.m4v?id=100&ext=m4v";    "
```

So I can send this asset library address to `MPMoviePlayerController` and it will work!

Like so:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"assets-library://asset/asset.m4v?id=100&ext=m4v";
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
etc...
```

now I just gotta figure out how to get that URL string out of the ALAsset object dynamically, which shouldn't be too hard to figure out.. hopefully

Answer (score 3):

Even easier

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerVC =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The URL contains something like `assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=12345&ext=mov`. The MoviePlayerController doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `url` of an `asset` by using:

```
[result defaultRepresentation] url];
```

Answer (score 0):

@go2 answer is correct but  The MoviePlayerController doesn't show anything.

so you also need to add      `moviePlayerController.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeFile;` 
see below code to play this.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
moviePlayerController.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```