# Play videos from iPad with out import into my app

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, alassetslibrary, video-player

In my app I want to play already saved videos from user's iPad. normally we use UIimagePickercontroller for import assets in our apps. but in my case i want to play video file without importing or saving in my app.
i already check the UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL which shows path of y app it means fail is planing from temporary folder *file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/137E6A4A-3777-4926-8D52-434C2E3EDC0C/tmp/trim.4BAC5E82-D175-4ABD-BC9A-E3A8FF0D5551.MOV*

I found some links witch are help you guys  to understand
[display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

[play video from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865110/play-video-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-ios?lq=1)

Comment: search for tutorials on MPMoviePlayerController. Once you have NSURL for the movie its very easy to play it using that controller.

Comment: "which shows path of y app it means fail is planing from temporary folder" ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in my case i want to play video file without importing or saving
>   in my app

To achieve this, you have to know the ALAsset url of the desired video. Use `ALAssetLibrary` to load the video using ALAsset url.

You can display all the Photolibrary videos using `UIimagePickercontroller` and you can get the url of the video's when user choosing one from this. Save those url to your application storage and play it again while you need (using `ALAsset` and saved ALAsset url).

Comment: thanks . but when we use UIimagePickercontroller and select any video they give temp url how can i get ALAsset url ?

Comment: @FaheemRajput use  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController )picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 

NSURL imageUrl = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 

}

and convert this to string. The url is look like "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000246&ext=JPG".