# How do I get a thumbnail or saveable path from UIImagePickerController to use for a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, alasset

Could somebody please explain or show some sample code of how I can use get a thumbnail to be put into a UIImageView after the user selects a photo with UIImagePickerController?

Let's say I want to set a thumbnail as the image of a table view cell. When the user presses the cell, the image picker is shown and the user selects an image that is already on their device. I also want to save the path to that thumbnail so that the next time the view is displayed, the proper thumbnail can be shown.

I am able to display an image picker and my delegate get's the chosen image correctly, but I want the path to the thumbnail, and I want to load the thumbnail using that path (i.e. I want to save the path).
I've searched for hours today and haven't figured this out. Perhaps I'm not understanding ALAsset, or maybe it is something else, but I can't find any examples that are helping me. I have never used the image picker or ALAsset before now, so I'm completely new at this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

//If you are reading this and look at the comments below and think ??WTF?? it is because I am editing my original Answer instead of posting two Answers in hopes that things will be cleaner. It is important to know that ALAssetsLibrary is an iOS 4.x thing.

The code below will function to take an asset-library URL and then make a UIImage out of the thumbnail representation. Though I use the asset-library url directly there is no reason that this same code couldn't begin by transforming a string representation into a NSURL in order to satisfy the `imageURL` assignment. Disclaimer: this code probably leaks or something worse, but it answers the original poster's question and is hopefully of value.

The code below is borrowing heavily on t[his Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone) that covers basically this same topic. In addition to the code here, I have included AssetsLibrary.framework and the ALAssetsLibrary typedefs referenced in the other question.

The whole trick is that you cannot reference the NSURL from an asset-library directly. I think (though I don't know) that it is somehow referencing a data store instead of a file so the data returned from the URL isn't straight NSData so you cannot use it the old way.

There is a UIImageView in the code that is called `photo`. Hopefully everything else is easy to figure out.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSLog(@"%@",imageURL);
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        CGImageRef iref = [myasset thumbnail];
        if (iref) {
            UIImage *theThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
            [[self photo] setImage:theThumbnail];

        }
    };


    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"booya, cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };

    if(imageURL)
    {
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL 
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If you don't want the thumbnail but do want the full photo, you will just change the code in the AssetForURLResult block to something like this:

```
       ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
```

We can leave that exercize for the user.

Good luck, hope this helps clear things up for you.

Comment: If the user deletes the image from the camera roll, it won't be a problem, the picture in my view will just be left blank. The picture is not a necessity to the rest of the view.

Comment: The picture is not a necessity to the rest of the view. I am targeting IOS 4.0 and higher. To make it easy, let's say I want to put the full size image into a UIImageView. How can I do that if I only have the NSURL object from the info dictionary? The things I have tried so far have not worked, I suppose I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The NSURL object would point to the image and then you can download it. Since you're targeting IOS 4.0, you do have the option of going to the Asset Library itself. There is a tutorial at iCode blog (http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/) but maybe you've seen it already? Once you have the asset in hand, you can use the valueForPropery method and grab the ALAssetPropertyURLs which is a dictionary containing file URL's.

Comment: When I get the NSURL object from the image picker results and hover over the object while debugging, it is printed as something like "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=10000000002&ext=JPG". If I create an NSData object using dataWithContentsOfURL:chosenPictureNSURL, it fails. I have seen the tutorial you linked, but I don't understand how to us the Asset Library to just get one picture, nor can I find any examples when searching. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 2):

I've got it mostly figured out now. The difficulty I had was understanding Blocks, mostly the syntax of Blocks made it difficult to understand what they are and how they work.

In the delegate for the UIImagePickerController, when the user has selected an image, you can get the path to the picture in the assets library using:

```
NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

With that object, you can get the full size image or a thumbnail using the following code:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        // Gets the full size image
        self.fullSizeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }

    // Gets the thumbnail
    self.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[myasset thumbnail]];
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"in failureblock, got an error: %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};

ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLib assetForURL:urlForImage resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
```

This page really helped me understand Blocks: [Blocks in iOS 4](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1)
See also [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Saving the URL can be problematic:

1. at least in iOS 4.x, the URLs is not guaranteed to be unique. They can be reused if user deletes/add pictures, which is obviously common. So, the URL you kept can point to a different picture in the future!
2. When the user updates to iOS 5, the URLs are no longer valid. UGH!!! Apple has rewritten Photo Library, with no backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image you select from imagePicker into Documents Directory instaed of referencing it from the picker
Here is the code you can use for saving image. Implement this method in the callback method invoked when user selects a photo from the picker

```
 NSFileManager   fileManager    = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray*  output_PDF_paths  =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString* output_PDF_documentsDirectory = [output_PDF_paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* output_PDF_ABSOLUTE_PATH  = [output_PDF_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageName.png"];  

    BOOL success_new = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfilePhotoselected) writeToFile:previewPagePath atomically:YES];
```

//Here the "ProfilePhotoselected" is the image which you get from the picker as a argument in your callabck method

Comment: This is one way to do it, but the problem is I will also have to implement code that can delete pictures from the documents directory that are no longer being used, not to mention it will just require more space. Ideally, I would like the picture to only be stored in the camera roll and if the user deletes the image from there, no big deal, my code will just not display an image.