# Trouble Sending Parameter to Main Thread From Async Block

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary

I have the following method which retrieves an `ALAsset` from the `UIImagePicker` after it snaps a photo. It then attempts to send this `ALAsset` to another one of my methods via the main thread:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] retain];
    __block ALAsset *result;

    [self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
    {
        result = [asset retain];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            [self loadPhotoImageViewWithAsset:result];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [imageURL release];
            [result release];
        });
    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {

    }];
}
```

When I get into the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ block`, `result` is showing as `nil`. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [UIImagePickerController to use for a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664686/1106035) for result is showing as nil.

Use like this:

```
 [self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
{
    result = [asset retain];
    [self loadPhotoImageViewWithAsset:result];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [imageURL release];
    [result release];   
}
failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{

}];
```

Change your `loadPhotoImageViewWithAsset` Method

```
-(void)loadPhotoImageViewWithAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
  //dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
   //dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
     //here code for loading image
    });
  // });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works when I use the UIImagePicker to select a photo from a photo library. When I try to use it with the camera it doesn't, so I guess the issue more has to do the camera.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL has a url for picking a photo and capture a photo. So code remains same

Comment: The issue is photos taken with the imagepicker arent going to my photo library for some reason. Marked yours as correct cause you answered me question, thanks.