# iphone retrieve image using URL using ALAsset

Tags: iphone, image, upload, alasset

I want to know how to how to retrieve a image using URL. I am using the ALAsset. I followed the answer (the one with the tick mark) from the following link  [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone). How to retrieve the image and upload it?

Answer (score 16):

Have you managed to get the ALAsset? Once you do, getting the image is easy. To get a thumbnail, the asset has a method...thumbnail.

`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[myAsset thumbnail]];`

To get the full Res image you have to go through the default representation.

`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[myAsset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but just in case anyone else comes I found another method (requires iOS 5+) that returns an easier to work with image:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[myAsset defaultRepresentation] 
               fullScreenImage];
```

From the docs of `fullScreenImage`:

In iOS 5 and later, this method returns a fully cropped, rotated, and adjusted image—exactly as a user would see in Photos or in the image picker.

monkybonk05's answer does work, but it not cropped or rotated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this method

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:representation.fullResolutionImage
                               scale:[representation scale]
                         orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[representation orientation]];
}
```

I've slightly adjusted it based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/NR4TR/8576048