# How to get image path from photo library and how to retrieve the image from photo library in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to iphone. In my small application, how to get image path from photo library. I use this following code to getting images and placed in imageview.

```
-(IBAction) selectimage
{
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
}
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
{
[UIPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageview.image=[info objectForKey:"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSLog("Image Path=%@",imageview.image);
}
```

Its succefully placed to Imageview. But i cant get its imagepath. I'm using nslog("%@",imageview.image); it shows "Image Path=" in console.
How can i get its path and how to retrieve photos from photo library. Any body help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` returns only the image's data, with no reference to its local storage. I haven't used it myself but I guess what you are looking for is

```
NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

At least, it's the only way I know of to retrieve any URL.

To retrieve the image, have a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone) But also keep in mind, that you already have the image retrieved with

```
UIImage* image=(UIImage*)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

so ask yourself if you really need this.

Comment: How to retrieve images. i used this code. its shows "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000007&ext=JPG" in console. how to retrieve image.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone). But also keep in mind, that you already have the image (via UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) so do you really need to access it this way?

Comment: anyway.. i need to place image to imageview and also change imageview when user wants to change photo. anycode u give me. also retrieve images. can u gve the code?

Comment: I just gave you the link on how to retrieve the image. Look, I edited my question again and it answers you question exactly. If you have further problems, please post a new question. Thanks :)

Comment: One reason to reference the underlying asset is to create a thumbnail of the image using AVAssetImageGenerator. Otherwise, you have to scale the image returned from the original image.

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 3.0, You can get imageData from referenceURL by following way

```
let url = URL(string: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000007&ext=JPG")
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
guard let result = asset.firstObject else {
  return nil
}
let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
var imageData: Data? = nil
imageManager.requestImageData(for: result, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data, string, orientation, dict) in
  imageData = data
})
```