# How to find out the file path of the image in Image Picker Controller call back

Tags: ios, xcode

In my ios which invokes Image Picker Controller to let user picks image from his phone.

I have implemented this callback when user finished picking the photo:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {

}
```

I would like to know if it is possible for me to find the file path of the image that the user has picked?  I am thinking after the user picks the photos, he may exist from my app. I want to resume the photos which he picked before in my app. Is that possible?

Comment: images aren't saved to the phone unless you specifically save them to disk. you can find the actual image in the callback using     UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; but unless you've implemented something like [ALAssetsLibrary sharedALAssetsLibrary] saveImage: meta:c toAlbum:withCompletionBlock:] it will be gone after you exit.

Comment: The imagePicker Controller picks image from Camera Roll, which are photos on the phone , Right?  So it should be there even when I exit my app. Is my understand correct?

Comment: i understand, i thought you were taking photos then hitting the callback. I haven't tried it and I haven't looked for a swift solution but what about this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777282/how-to-get-image-path-from-photo-library-and-how-to-retrieve-the-image-from-phot