# iOS5 Twitter Framework - Selecting an image from camera / camera roll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

I have created an application using the new Twitter framework in iOS 5, however I am struggling to add a feature to allow my users to add a photograph from the camera roll / take with camera.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Obviously I know I can use;

```
[tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

to add an image, but that is direct from the bundle as opposed to bringing up the devices camera roll.  I have tried messing around with UIImagePickerController but I cant get it functioning so not sure if I am barking up the wrong tree or if there is a set method in the Twitter framework for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the camera roll with the

`UIImagePickerController` which is the stock iOS object for this.

Then when you implement the delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"picker info - %@",info);
    [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    //do something with the URL
}
```

As the url is an asset URL rather than an absolute path.

You can use the info in this answer [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone/3845729#3845729) to access the hires image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have managed to access to camera roll and select an image. Having trouble to get it to attach it to a Tweet Sheet. im trying to assign the image to a UIImageView then say [tweetSheet addImage:imageView.image];