# How to get a UIImage object from a asset url

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am using ALAsset framework for selecting multiple images from the image library. I want to store the selected images into the database. These stored images are then to be used to show the slideshow of the images. My problem i am storing the image URL into the database, URL is in format - `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000007&ext=JPG`. Now for displaying the images i need UIImage object, so how do i create a UIImage object from this kind of URL. I have tried -

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in info)
 {

        NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];
    UIImage* ui;
    ui = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

}

This did not worked. Please some one tell me how do i do it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)