# Set Image on UIImageView using UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Is it possible to set the image on UIImageView using
   UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL . The traditional pattern is using 
[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

```
I tried this:
```

theImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]]];

But no image is set on UIImageView.

Please Help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
         {
           UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
             theImageView.image = copyOfOriginalImage;
         }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             // error handling
         }];
        [library release];
```

This code did the trick. :)

Comment: It would be helpful if someone Could convert it to Swift 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding four or five functions on one line, you need to do more error handling in your code.

Consider this instead:

```
NSURL * referenceURL = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
if(referenceURL == NULL)
{
    NSLog( @"reference URL is null");
} else {
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: referenceURL];
    if(imageData == NULL)
    {
        NSLog( @"no image data found for URL %@", [referenceURL absoluteString] );
    } else {
        UIImage * theActualImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
        if(theActualImage == NULL)
        {
            NSLog( @"the data at URL %@ is not an image", [referenceURL absoluteString] );
        } else {
            if(theImageView == NULL)
            {
                NSLog( @"I forgot to set theImageView" );
            } else {
                theImageView.image = theActualImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this info helps you out.

Comment: I got this in console
no image data found for URL assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=79450962-C0FD-484C-808B-83E045F40972&ext=JPG

But I selected an image from the Photo Gallery.
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure out where the problem was happening.  Now it looks like you need to figure out how to convert that reference URL into something you can actually load into an NSData object.  Maybe there is another key in the `info` NSDictionary that could help you?  :-)

Comment: BUt the URL seems to be a valid one :( Then why there is no image data?

Comment: You have to access that type of image data using `ALAssetsLibrary`.  Look for sample code that involves `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock`.

Comment: Sorry @Michael Dautermann didnt found anything helpfull on net. I am new to iphone. Can you please suggest me something.

Comment: [Look at the answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone).