# Play a video from video gallery in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an iPhone app,  in which I have to play multiple videos like "Top rated", "Most played","Favorites" etc.. Each category may have around 20 videos. So having around 100 videos inside resources folder increases the app size. So what I am trying to do is, first saving all the videos locally within the device and selecting the respective videos from the app whenever these videos needs to be played. So is it possible to do so?
Or have to have all the videos inside resources folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this is very well possible. you can store your videos in the device before instead of the  resources folder and use the [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get access to your videos stored in the photo library.

refer this on how to use the ALAssetsLibrary [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

Comment: :I dont want to select a video within app. I mean when I click on a video from list (from UITableView) it should play the corresponding video automatically by fetching the video from video gallery. And when I close it I should get back to the video list (i,e UITableView showing the video list)

Comment: yes that's what I am saying... using the ALAssetsLibrary you can get all the videos in photo library.. you can then display the list in table view and on selection play that particular video in a new view controller.