# How to show the specific image from PhotoLibrary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

In my Application I need to get specific image from Photo Library,

with use of **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** i am able to get the Imagename and ImagePath.

I am storing Imagename, ImagePath in Database.

But, how to show that specific image with use of the Imagename or ImagePath in Imageview from Photo Library?

Comment: is this after the image selection? display the selected image in a UIImageView? you can pass the image to UIImage like this. UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // for original image

Answer (score 3):

Please make use of `ALAssetLibrary`. To do this, add the `AssetsLibrary.framework` to your project and write the below code.

Your file name should look like `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000194&ext=JPG`

```
NSString *fileName = @"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000194&ext=JPG";

typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    UIImage *images = nil;

    if (iref)
    {
        images = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];       

        //doing UI operation on the main thread
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         yourImageView.image = images;

     });    

    }   
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"can't get image");
};    

NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
               resultBlock:resultblock   
              failureBlock:failureblock];
```

**Note:**

After the upgrade to iOS 5 and a code refactoring to make use of ARC, you will get an error as

> invalid attempt to access ALAssetPrivate past the lifetime of its
>   owning ALAssetsLibraryrefactoring to make use of ARC

To resolve this, add a static method to retrieve a shared instance of `ALAssetLibrary` class.

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library; 
}
```

Then, access it using `[MyClass defaultAssetsLibrary];`

```
[[MyClass defaultAssetsLibrary] assetForURL:asseturl 
                   resultBlock:resultblock   
                  failureBlock:failureblock];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have image path with you than you can use the following code. Lets take imagePath as NSString Variable that contains image path including image name.

```
   NSData *thedata=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
     UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:thedata]];
```

Hope it helps.