# Wedriver Windows popup handling

Tags: java, webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

My code is:

```
Set<String> windowsid = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterate = windowsid.iterator();

while(iterate.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterate.next());
}

String mainwindow_id = iterate.next();
String tabbedwindow_id = iterate.next();
```

I get an error @ `String mainwindow_id = iterate.next();`

Stating the below, Line 45 is the one i have in quotes.   
I have declared the `Set` as `String`

Please Help !

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:375)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
at windows.traverse.main(traverse.java:45)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the loop,

```
while(iterate.hasNext()){ 
    System.out.println(iterate.next()); 
}
```

there are no elements left in the set to iterate. You iterated through all the windows and that's why `NoSuchElementException`.

Can you explain a little bit about what you want to do?

If I understand you correctly, you dont need to use a loop.  Since there are only two windows, you can just do ..

```
Set<String> windowsid = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterate = windowsid.iterator();

String mainwindow_id = iterate.next();
String tabbedwindow_id = iterate.next();
```

Comment: The above prints me the window which is opened. After printing me the 2 windows it throws error. Basically i wanted to click an link and that opens an dynamic window. So i wanna perform some actions and then switch back to main window. Instead of while loop I simply used iterate.next(); twice it didn't work. used implicit wait after click even then a big no to all :(

Answer (score 1):

If loop has to be used then it's like

```
while(iterate.hasNext()){
    String st = iterate.next();
    System.out.println(st);
}
```