# How to access image from Asset URL in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, nsurl

I am getting asset URL from `NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];` and I saved it in a local database. And at the time of retrieving I have got an string and I have convert it into NSURL through `NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:image_path];` but when I get NSData from this URL through `NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];` it return NULL. Can anyone help me to get NSData and convert it into image.

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert it direct. You will have to use `ALAsset Block`. Here is the complete description for same thing.

[display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I am still getting error this [__NSCFConstantString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ac5c . The URL of my image is assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=83CAC75D-FF0F-44D6-B45C-85BABF32E71B&ext=JPG .