# How to modify image metadata ( EXIF ) in iOS without duplicating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exif

Currently the code I am using can write the updated metadata but creates a duplicate image. Here is the code :

```
if( [self.textView.text length] != 0 && ![self.userComments isEqualToString: self.textView.text])
        {
            // This code works but creates a duplicate image
            NSMutableDictionary *userCommentDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [userCommentDictionary setValue:self.textView.text forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dict setValue:userCommentDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

            ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

            [al writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[self.imageView.image CGImage]
                                metadata:dict
                         completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                             if (error == nil) {
                                 NSLog(@"Image saved.");
                                 self.userComments = self.textView.text;
                             } else {
                                 NSLog(@"Error saving image.");
                             }
                         }];
        }
```

Is there anyway to avoid duplication ? 
Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. AssetsLibrary doesn't allow modifying of the original asset at all, everything is saved as a new asset with a reference to the original. With the new PhotoKit library they do, but I do not see anything there that allows you to modify the  metadata either.

Comment: @JackWu You are correct. Please add as answer.

Comment: @JackWu, seconded. Do put it in answer form for anyone else who stumbles upon this (plus otherwise half the bounty will go to anyone who takes your comment and paraphrases it in the box below!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comment, I don't believe this is possible.

**AssetsLibrary** doesn't allow modifying of the original asset at all, everything is saved as a new asset with a reference to the original.

With the new **PhotoKit** library in iOS 8 they do allow modifying of the asset, but I do not see anything there that allows you to modify the metadata either.

Taking a glance at **ImageIO** there are methods to modify metadata, but again, nothing to save it to the photo library. 
With this, however, you could probably replace a file on disk with another one with modified exif data.

*edit to elaborate*:
According to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone) it seems like ALAssets provide a URL that does not point to the disk. I believe that means that you have no way of getting the acutual URL of the image to overwrite it, though not in the photos library.

I would suggest you file this as an enhancement to Apple if its that important, if many people request the same thing, they might add it in the future! It does seem that they don't want people messing with this stuff though..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will ImageIO let me replace the original image? It would be nice to get a definitive answer on that.

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee I edited to elaborate a bit. I would say no, there is no way you can modify the metadata of an existing photos library image.

Comment: I thnk PhotoKit allows you to edit metadata of the original image. Here is some text from Apple Docs " You use the photo library object to perform changes to Photos objects, such as editing asset metadata or content, inserting new assets, or rearranging the members of a collection."

Comment: You can trust me when I say it doesn't allow it. By "metadata" they mean stuff like `dateCreated`, `location`, `isFavorite`, `isHidden`. That's actually about it. You can dig into the API and see for yourself.

Comment: Oh , I thought metadata would mean all the metaData of the image. Thanks for the info.