# iOS - display image from `ALAssetLibrary`

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`. 
`ViewController1` is `UICollectionView` and it use `ASAssetLibrary` to load thumbnail into `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
NSMutableArray *collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [TemplateEditBarController defaultAssetsLibrary];
[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if (asset) {
              [collector addObject:asset];
          }
      }];
     assetsarray = collector;//<--assetsarray is local.
 }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error) { NSLog(@"fail!");}
 ];
```

When `cell` selected, I want to pass either `NSString` or `NSURL` to `ViewController2` so that it will call and display the full resolution image. But when `NSLog` the url:

```
ALAsset* asset = backgroundsarray[row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    NSURL *url = [representation url];
    newbg = [url absoluteString];//<-NSLog this.
```

I get:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6E5438ED-9A8C-4ED0-9DEA-AB2D8F8A9360&ext=JPG

I tried change to `[url path]` I get:

> asset.JPG

How can I get the actual photo url so that I can convert to `NSString` to pass to `ViewController2`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone  see the URL

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];        
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:aURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
     {
         UIImage  *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];             
         imageView.image=image;             

     }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
         // error handling
         NSLog(@"failure-----");
     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution here:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    if (asset) {
       image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]];
    }
}
```

Comment: But i don't know why the loaded image have the resolution that isn't full.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there isn't any direct solution other than passing `ALAsset`. This is what I do:

In `ViewController1`, which is `UICollectionViewController`, I have this function:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//NSLog(@"selected row: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
long row = [indexPath row];
NSString* newbg = [[NSString alloc]init];
if ([bartype isEqualToString:@"photolibrary"]) {
    ALAsset* asset = backgroundsarray[row];
    [_delegate changeBackgroundWithAsset:asset];
```

}

Then I have a function in `ViewController2` to process `ALAsset`:

```
-(void)changeBackgroundWithAsset:(ALAsset*)b{
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [b defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
UIImage *bimage;
bimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
UIImageView* bgview = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
bgview = curbgview;
bgview.image = bimage;
```

}