# UImage get local url after save ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to saved an image in my photo albums, however I had succesfully saved the image but now I want to get the URL which would be my local URL that would open the image If I passes that to `UIImage`. I'm unable to get the saved image url as of error that "expression not allowed". How can I get the `LOCAL URL` of my saved image in `iOS`.

My Tried:

```
-(NSString *) imageSave: (UIImage *)image
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error )
         {
             [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset )
              {
                  self.temp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];
                  NSLog(@"SAVED!");
              }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error )
              {
                   self.temp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO"];
                  NSLog(@"Error Saving Image!!!");
              }];
         }];

    return self.temp1;
}
```

I tried by ma making a property but that returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code that may help you.

```
UIImage *viewImage = YOUR UIIMAGE  // --- 
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
// Request to save the image to camera roll  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error) {  
        NSLog(@"error");  
    } else {  
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);
        NSString *myString = [assetURL absoluteString];

    }  
}];
```

Comment: Where would be the ImageURL in your code that would be my output ?

Comment: It's ... NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);

Comment: I know there is the URL, but I want to output that. Please look at my post title, I want to take the output from assetURL.

Comment: you said  How can I get the LOCAL URL of my saved image in iOS.

Comment: what you want is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone

Comment: yes, I want to get the local url but not on log, as output of NSString.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88137/discussion-between-developer-and-piyush-patel).