# How can i get UIImage from Asset Library Url in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I want to get `UIImage` from Asset Library Url

I'm an developing app in xamarin ios, trying to get a UIImage Object from a given Asset-Library-Url.

Picked multiple images from gallery using `ELCImagePickerViewController`.
All image paths are added in string array list.
Now i need to get all the images in `Byte[]` using the Asset-Library-Url path.

The given Url is:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=0E126068-14F9-431F-91B5-8BC397727656&ext=JPG

I tried it with the following approach :

```
static UIImage FromUrl(string uri)
{
   using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
   using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
   return UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
}
```

But it always returns null.
Can anybody please tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

These Urls are for the `ALAssetsLibrary`, you will need to use the `ALAssetsLibrary` to access them. See example below:

```
public Byte[] LoadAssetAsByteArray(string uri)
{
    var nsUrl = new NSUrl(uri);
    var asset = new ALAssetsLibrary();
    Byte[] imageByteArray = new Byte[0];
    UIImage image;

    asset.AssetForUrl(nsUrl,(ALAsset obj) => {

      var assetRep = obj.DefaultRepresentation;
      var cGImage = assetRep.GetFullScreenImage();
      image = new UIImage(cGImage);
      // get as Byte[]
      imageByteArray = new Byte[image.AsPNG().Length];
      //imageView.Image = image;
    }, 
    (NSError err) => { 
        Console.WriteLine(err);
    });

    return imageByteArray;
}
```

There is a great recipe using a `UIImagePickerController` on the [Xamarin Site](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/choose_a_photo_from_the_gallery/) which I beleive would help you