# Get Lat. Lon from iPhone photo library photos

Tags: iphone, mapkit, coordinates, photo, photolibrary

How can i get access to the users iPhone photo library and get the lat, lon information for those photos?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latitude/longitude information, if it's there, will be in the EXIF section of the JPG file. Check out this exif iPhone library:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/

See also: [iPhone - access location information from a photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616346/iphone-access-location-information-from-a-photo)